# Determinitic finite automaton (DFA) that accepts natural numbers divisible by 6

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'm new to Formal Systems and Automata and I'm working on some exercises to get familiar with the concepts.

I want to create a DFA that accepts natural numbers divisible by 6. I know that a number is divisible by 6, if it is divisible by 2 and divisible by 3.

What is the correct approach here to get a minimal automaton? Should I just create two automata, one for divisibility by 2 and one for divisibility by 3, and create the intersection of both or how would you do that?

Comment: http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~fstephan/finiteautomata.html may be helpful

Comment: You may also find this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22282792/2297725) helpful. You basically create a DFA with $6$ states, one for each possible remainder. If you are in state $a$ and see a digit $b$, you move to state $\text{mod}(10a+b,6)$.

Comment: @achille hui That's a lot of transitions. Is this the smallest solution?

Comment: Also, is there only one accepting state, namely q0?

Comment: This is not the smallest one becomes $\gcd(10,6) = 2 \ne 1$. It is the minimal one in a base $b$ where $\gcd(b,6) = 1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I understood you last comment correctly. Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: Are your numbers written in binary?